# How to provide authentication for web service post requests in cakephp

Tags: android, rest, cakephp, authentication, restful-authentication

I'm developing webstite using cakePhp. I use the Auth component from cake and also the Acl component for users/permissions. All work fine in the web end. I now want to call some controllers' actions from another device (Android) phone and I want to provide some sort of security for the password. so my qyestions are :

1 - How to secure or encrypt the password in Android client so that I can decrypt in cake (any well knowns or standards for that ?)

2- In the cakebackend , How to and where can I use the decrypted password to allow the response for the user based on his credentials

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use https

2) What you want is stateless authentication.

- http://appsandsecurity.blogspot.de/2011/04/rest-and-stateless-session-ids.html
- [How to implement a stateless REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864761/how-to-implement-a-stateless-rest-api)

There are plenty of resources online if you search for "sateless authentication" and many sample scripts.